# New Issue on Fedora 36 with plotting and pandas

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I was using this on RHEL8 and earlier with no issues but a colleague tried my tool with Fedora 36 that has a different (newer) version of pandas/matplotlib

```
matplotlib         3.6.1     /home/loberman/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages pip
pandas             1.5.1     /home/loberman/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages pip
```

Code is really simple:

```
cpu_mem_data = read_csv(fname_mem, sep=' ', index_col=1, parse_dates=True)
cpumain = cpu_mem_data[['CPU-Wait%','CPU-User%','CPU-Nice%','CPU-Sys%',]]

cpumain.plot(grid='on',subplots='True',style=['r','g','b','y'],sharex=True,kind='area',title=plot_title+' cpu-view')
```

This has never failed for almost 10 years but now I get an error I cannot figure out. I don't know how it wants me to put the columns=['x',y'] tuples in.

Error I now see is this.

```
  File "/home/loberman/collectl-parser/./parse-collectl-python3.py", line 264, in <module>
    cpumain.plot(grid='on',subplots='True',style=['r','g','b','y'],sharex=True,kind='area',title=plot_title+' cpu-view')
  File "/home/loberman/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py", line 1000, in __call__
    return plot_backend.plot(data, kind=kind, **kwargs)
  File "/home/loberman/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/__init__.py", line 70, in plot
    plot_obj = PLOT_CLASSES[kind](data, **kwargs)
  File "/home/loberman/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/core.py", line 1530, in __init__
    LinePlot.__init__(self, data, **kwargs)
  File "/home/loberman/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/core.py", line 1337, in __init__
    MPLPlot.__init__(self, data, **kwargs)
  File "/home/loberman/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/core.py", line 187, in __init__
    self.subplots = self._validate_subplots_kwarg(subplots)
  File "/home/loberman/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/core.py", line 352, in _validate_subplots_kwarg
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: When subplots is an iterable, each entry should be a list/tuple of column names.
```

---

Adding to this in case it helps others:

I downgraded to 1.4 and its works like it used to now.

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting pandas==1.4
  Downloading pandas-1.4.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (11.7 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 11.7 MB 2.7 MB/s            
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.8.1 in /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from pandas==1.4) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2020.1 in /home/loberman/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from pandas==1.4) (2022.5)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.21.0 in /home/loberman/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from pandas==1.4) (1.23.4)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.8.1->pandas==1.4) (1.16.0)
Installing collected packages: pandas
  Attempting uninstall: pandas
    Found existing installation: pandas 1.5.1
    Uninstalling pandas-1.5.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pandas-1.5.1
Successfully installed pandas-1.4.0
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! In the question, you mentioned that downgrading solved it the issue. Am I getting that right? If so, please add that information as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading pip3 pandas to 1.4 from 1.51 solved this for me.
However I still don't know what pandas 1.5 is looking for now in the subplot command so an example would be useful for others.